# htaccess 301 redirect url without subdirectories

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect this url:

https:///www.domain.com/courses/company/

to this one:

https:///www.domain.com/courses/

**without** also redirecting these:

https:///www.domain.com/courses/company/123/
https:///www.domain.com/courses/company/456/

I first tried this:

Redirect 301 /courses/company/ /courses/

but that also redirected the urls with the subdirectories.

Next I tried this:

Redirect 301 /courses/company/$ /courses/ ...because I thought the $ sign makes it match exactly that url.

But it didn't redirect anything.

Thanks!

Comment: For future questions please learn how to use code formatting here on SO. It makes reading your question so much easier ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the `Redirect` directive is that it does not allow to use "regular expressions" as you tried to do. It only implements a simple prefix string matching approach.

Instead you'd have to use the `RedirectMatch` directive which does support such expressions:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/courses/company/?$ /courses/
```

See the documentation of the [`RedirectMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) directive.

Instead you could also use the more flexible rewrite module:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?courses/company/?$ courses/ [L,R=301]
```

And a general hint: it usually is a good idea to start out with a `302` *temporary* redirection. And to only change that to the `301` *permanent* redirection once everything works as intended. That prevents nasty caching issues for your clients.